# Different outcome of java multi-thread due to length of sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading

This code end up with different results if I change the parameter of **sleep()**, and here is some sample outcomes:

1.**sleep(1l)**, the thread will always terminate automaticlly, the "Stoped" statement will always be printed, and the icon of "Terminate" in Eclipse will be grey too. (seems working perfectly huh?)

2.**sleep(1000l)**,  here comes the problem, if main thread sleeps for 1 second, the Thread v will never terminated automaticlly, the "Stoped" will not be printed, and the icon of "Terminate" is red, which means there is still some thread running.

**I know it could be solved if I add "volitale" for the parameter "isRunning", but I wonder why and how does the sleep() statement affect the outcome?**

PS:I'm a newbie for both java and english, so I apologize for any possible discomforts due to this question.

```
public class VolitaleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Vo v = new Vo();
        new Thread(v).start();
        Thread.sleep(1000l);
        v.setRunning(false);
        System.out.println(v.i);
    }
}

class Vo implements Runnable {

    private boolean isRunning = true;
    int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            i++;
            // System.out.println("Running");
            /*
             * Once you add this statement, you will always be able to terminate
             * the program automatically, no matter how long the thread sleeps.
             */
        }
        System.out.println("Stoped.");
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = isRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: `isRunning` needs to be `volatile`.

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/106787/6785649) can help with your understanding as to what is happening.

Comment: @EJP or use an `AtomicBoolean`.

Comment: @flakes Or synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`volatile` makes it possible for what one thread wrote up to and including writing to the `volatile` variable to be visible to another thread starting from when it reads that variable. If the variable is not `volatile` then that *happens-before* memory relationship is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I'm starting to understand this.